# Simple discrete math subsets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Here I have a problem that asks me to determine whether the first set is the subset of the second, or the second set is the subset of the first, or neither is a subset of the other.

1st set = the set of airline flights from New York to New Delhi
2nd set = the set of nonstop airline flights from New York to New Delhi

The solution offered by the book is as follows: Because every nonstop flight is a flight, every element in the first set is also an element in the second set, so the first set is a subset of the second. Because there are flights that do have intermediate stops (say, from New York to Atlanta with a stop in Detroit), the second set is not a subset of the first.

To me it seems that the first set would consist of all flights including nonstop flights and flights with intermediate stops, so that the second set would be a subset of the first.

I'm not sure if I'm overthinking it or just missing something that is very clear and obvious.

Thank you in advance for any help!
Much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It appears that the person writing the book's solutions got the labels of the sets switched around.

Comment: The book has a typo.  Every element of the *second* set is an element of the *first* set so the *second* set is a subset of the *first*.  And as not every element of the *first* set is non-stop the *first* set is not a subset of the *second*.  So you are right and the book is ... well, the book just mislabeled.   .... completely mislabeled....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book made an error in labelling.

As every non-stop flight is a flight the *set of non-stop flights* is a subset of the *set of flights*.

And as not ever flight is non-stop the *set of flights* is not a subset of the *set of non-stop flights*.

Now the book seems have mixed things up and is claiming *1st set* = *set of non-stop flights* and *2nd set* = *set of flights*.

BUT clearly in the beginning it was claiming the *exact* opposite.

It was a mistake.  It doesn't matter *what* we label the as long as we are consistent.  Which the book wasn't.

Upshot

If $A = $*set of non-stop flights* and $B =$ *set of flights* then:

$A \subset B$ and $B \not \subset A$.

I think you understand and get this.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct and the book is wrong.

Let $AF$ = the set of airline flights from New York to New Delhi

and $NAF$ = the set of nonstop airline flights from New York to New Delhi

Since every nonstop airline flights from New York to New Delhi is an airline flight  from New York to New Delhi,  the set $NAF$ is a subset of $AF$

Thus $NAF \subseteq AF$

Comment: But I think we should point out the OP was correct and the book was not, in that the book first clamed "first set" =AF and "second set" = NAF, but then in the explanation switched it to "first set" = NAF and "second set" = AF.

Comment: Thanks, I added that statement to my answer.